# Run a QProcess inside QWidget

Tags: qt

I tried very much, I want solution to run executable file inside Widget?  Can anyone help me out.

Comment: What kind of executable is it (a console application for example)?  Or do you what to run _any_ kind of application?

Comment: I suspect you want to display the GUI of a different executable in a widget inside your own application?

Comment: i want to run exe inside a  QWidget

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you're after something like what Tim Meyer commented.  In that case you should build the other application to use widgets from an external shared object (dll) so to allow the use of the class/widget you need in multiple executables.

QProcess won't be able to do this since it's used to spawn executables in their own environment.